# An algorithm to position events in a column in javascript to be able to create a calendar

Tags: javascript, angular, algorithm

I want to build a **calendar** and I have started with one day view. I haven't realise that at the beginning that it is quite a complex problem. Also I can not use external library. I came out with a naive approach that I am calculating a neighbours to each event and then I am dividing a width by its neighbours but I feel that I am far from an optimal solution.

https://github.com/marekpanti/calendar-events-prototype/blob/master/src/app/components/calendar/calendar.service.ts. -> my algorithm

I have intervals:

```
export const dummyEvents = [
  {
    start: new Date(new Date().setHours(8)),
    end: new Date(new Date().setHours(20)),
    id: 1,
    meta: {}
  },
  {
    start: new Date(new Date().setHours(8)),
    end: new Date(new Date().setHours(10)),
    id: 2,
    meta: {}
  },
  {
    start: new Date(new Date().setHours(8)),
    end: new Date(new Date().setHours(10)),
    id: 3,
    meta: {}
  },
  {
    start: new Date(new Date().setHours(11)),
    end: new Date(new Date().setHours(16)),
    id: 4,
    meta: {}
  },
  {
    start: new Date(new Date().setHours(15)),
    end: new Date(new Date().setHours(16)),
    id: 5,
    meta: {}
  },
  {
    start: new Date(new Date().setHours(15)),
    end: new Date(new Date().setHours(16)),
    id: 6,
    meta: {}
  },
];
```

```
getEventsPosition() {
const overlappingEvents: any[] = [];
// shallow copy needed so we won't mutate the original object
this.convertedEventsInTimeline = dummyEvents.map((a) => Object.assign({}, a));
// sort all events by start
this.convertedEventsInTimeline.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
  if (a.start.getTime() > b.start.getTime()) return 1;
  return -1;
});

// start checking events for collisions
this.convertedEventsInTimeline.forEach((event: any) => {
  let collisionCounter = 0;
  const collisions: any[] = [];

  event.meta = { ...event.meta, top: this.calcEventOffsetTop(event), height: this.calcEventHeight(event) };
  if (!event.meta.width) {
    event.meta = { ...event.meta, width: 0, left: 0 };
  }

  // Comparing next events with our selected pointer
  for (let j = 0; j < this.convertedEventsInTimeline.length; j++) {
    if (
      this.doesOverlap(event, this.convertedEventsInTimeline[j]) &&
      event.id !== this.convertedEventsInTimeline[j].id
    ) {
      collisionCounter += 1;
      // Creating
      collisions.push(this.convertedEventsInTimeline[j]);
    }
  }
  overlappingEvents.push({ collisions: collisionCounter, id: event.id, collisionEvents: collisions });
});

overlappingEvents.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.collisions < b.collisions) return 1;
  return -1;
});


// set width and left to our events
if (overlappingEvents) {
  // iterate the overlappingEvents
  overlappingEvents.forEach((overlappingGroup) => {
    let maxWidth = 1;
    let leftOffsetCounter = 0;
    const outterIndex = this.convertedEventsInTimeline.findIndex((e: any) => e.id === overlappingGroup.id);
    // Iterate inner cycle only if width is not set, otherwise we are done
    if (this.convertedEventsInTimeline[outterIndex].meta.width === 0) {
      console.log('ziadna sirka');
      // firstly find the max inner collisions
      overlappingGroup.collisionEvents.forEach((overlappedEvent: any) => {
        const index = this.convertedEventsInTimeline.findIndex((e: any) => e.id === overlappedEvent.id);
        if (maxWidth < overlappingEvents[index].collisions) {
          maxWidth = overlappingEvents[index].collisions;
        }
      });
      // set the width for outter Cycle event
      const index = this.convertedEventsInTimeline.findIndex((e: any) => e.id === overlappingGroup.id);
      this.convertedEventsInTimeline[index].meta.width = maxWidth + 1;

      // set width for all collisions inside main, start positioning
      overlappingGroup.collisionEvents.forEach((overlappedEvent: any) => {
        const innerIndex = this.convertedEventsInTimeline.findIndex((e: any) => e.id === overlappedEvent.id);
        this.convertedEventsInTimeline[innerIndex].meta.width = maxWidth + 1;
        // start the positioning, from left, if it reaches maxWidth, it means
        // that the next interval is bigger, so it can be glued to parent
        if (leftOffsetCounter <= maxWidth) {
          leftOffsetCounter += 1;
        } else {
          leftOffsetCounter = 1;
        }
        this.convertedEventsInTimeline[innerIndex].meta.left = leftOffsetCounter;
      });
    }

    // make sure if there are no collisions to set width to 100%
    if (overlappingGroup.collisions === 0) {
      this.convertedEventsInTimeline[outterIndex].meta.width = 1;
    }
  });
}
return this.convertedEventsInTimeline;
```

[image: visualisation of a solution]

In my solution each event has width of 100% / 6, but I would like it to have 100% / 4 as there are 4 events from 12 - 17. Ideally I would like to obtain something like that:
[image]
https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-calendar/#/kitchen-sink

Could you navigate me to some better solution, or maybe completely other approach from mine?

Comment: *"my algorithm"*: please post the relevant code inside your post. Links could be interesting as background information, but a question should be self contained. *"better solution"*: what is better is a matter of opinion. *"Ideally I would like to obtain something like that"*: this is something you could tell a programmer that you hire for the job.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I've added here my algorithm as well as screenshot of my desired solution